# Import All Access Table Data Into SQL Server Table

Tags: c#, sql-server, ms-access-2013, sqlbulkcopy

I am needing to take all of my access tables and create the exact same table in SQL Server 2008 with data and keys/constraints.  The below syntax will insert data if the table already exists, but how do I do it if the table does not exist?  Or is there a better method programmatic ally in play to already achieve this result?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AccessToSQL
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    const string databaselocation = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Database1.accdb;Persist Security Info = False;";
    List<string> tables = new List<string>();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetTableNames();
        const string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Database1.accdb;Persist Security Info = False;";
        const string connectionStringDest = "Data Source = TO\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Testing;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
        using (var sourceConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            sourceConnection.Open();
            using (var destinationConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionStringDest))
            {
                destinationConnection.Open();
                foreach (string tbl in tables)
                {
                    var commandSourceData = new OleDbCommand("Select * from "+tbl, sourceConnection);
                    var reader = commandSourceData.ExecuteReader();
                    using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(destinationConnection))
                    {
                        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo."+tbl;
                        try { bulkCopy.WriteToServer(reader); }
                        catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
                        finally { reader.Close(); }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public List<string> GetTableNames()
    {
        try {
            using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(databaselocation))
            {
                con.Open();
                //DataTable schema = con.GetSchema("Columns");
                //foreach (DataRow row in schema.Rows)
                //{
                //    tables.Add(row.Field<string>("TABLE_NAME"));
                //}
                foreach (DataRow r in con.GetSchema("Tables").Select("TABLE_TYPE = 'TABLE'"))
                {
                    tables.Add(r["TABLE_NAME"].ToString());
                }
                return tables;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
        return tables;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: SQL Server has a wizard to import Access Databases, SSMS has a wizard to import data from Access. Why are you trying to do the same thing with code?

Comment: Check [SQL Server Migration Assistant for Access](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh313039(v=sql.110).aspx)

Comment: With the SQL Server wizard to import access database can you choose only tables?

Comment: Access also has an upscale utility.

Comment: The import wizard allows you to select what to import.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos when I start this wizard the only options for access I see are Microsoft Jet or Microsoft Access Database Engine neither of which see my .accdb

Comment: Your connection string *already* uses the Access Database Engine driver (`Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0`). Have you tried opening an `accdb` file?

Comment: You'll need the data connectivity components to connect to an accdb.  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734